# Is there a documentclass for stage or screenplays?

Tags: document-classes

I need to convert a stage play from an ODT document to LaTeX.  I am hoping to find a documentclass that implements the conventional script formatting (vs published formatting) as described below:

- http://www.gordonstate.edu/PT_Faculty/lking/CPF_play_formatting2.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenplay#Format_and_style

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dramatist, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/screenplay, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stage and the whole CTAN topic https://www.ctan.org/topic/drama-script.

Comment: And we have some questions related to  [tag:dramatist] here

Comment: I've used [plari](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/plari) although I ended up making quite a few modifications in the preamble as it was for a TV script rather than a stage play.